How to effectively "remove" clauses from a query, if no params are provided
I am trying to query some data as part of an APEX form and if a value isn't supplied I basically want to remove the clause for it entirely, or effectively nullify it.
So, let's say I have this query
select job_name, state, last_start_date
  from all_scheduler_jobs
 where owner = user
and job_name = :P69_JOB_NAME;

If the value for :P69_JOB_NAME isn't supplied, I need to treat it like the clause never existed. So, effectively, the query would be:
select job_name, state, last_start_date
  from all_scheduler_jobs
 where owner = user;

So, the way I have come up to no-op this is as such:
select job_name, state, last_start_date
  from all_scheduler_jobs
 where owner = user
and job_name = regexp_like(DEFINITION,COALESCE(DECODE(:P69_JOB_NAME , '',null), :P69_JOB_NAME,'.*'));

Which works in that use of .* will always produce true, and thus I have a clause of ... and true
The problem is that, on the real data (not the job table) it's cranking through 10^8 records, and there are multiple clauses like this. So it's horribly slow.
How can I achieve this same effect without the performance penalty? Ideally without creating a dynamic query. This may not be possible

I'm not sure if this will work for your exact case, but a trick I've done is coalescing to the left hand value ex. where someField = coalesce(somethingThatMightBeNull, someField)

To remove the clause effectively you need to use Dynamic SQL. That is, to assemble the query by adding the required sections only when needed. The no-op solution does produce the correct result, but typically generates low-performance queries.

Usual approach is to convert the 1st query you posted to
select job_name, state, last_start_date
  from all_scheduler_jobs
 where owner = user
  and (job_name = :P69_JOB_NAME or :P69_JOB_NAME is null)

The same goes with all other parameters query might take. Would it work? Certainly! However, performance gets worse and worse.
Apex guys suggest we switch to a function body returning SQL query. You can write it directly in Apex, or - as I did - create a stored function (possibly as a part of a package), pass as many parameters as needed, and then relatively simply (IF-THEN-ELSE simpler, dynamic SQL somewhat more complex) compose the whole WHERE clause to be attached to the rest of the SELECT statement.
It works, and it works faster than the 1st approach I mentioned.
